# Wordpress: When updating user roles, the capabilities does not change

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I created custom user roles - partner and distributor. The partner can see the inventory page, order page and client page. while the distributor can only see the order page and client page. I am using advanced access manager and I can now restrict the pages that each user can see.

Now, I want to update the user role of a certain user, from distributor to partner. I used the following code:

```
wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $userID, 'role' => 'partner') ) ;
```

When I echo the user role, I am getting partner. But I can only see 2 pages (order page and client page) instead of 3 pages (inventory, order and client page)

What should I do? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## More specifically, a user's role can be set by creating an instance of the WP_user class, and calling the add_role() or remove_role() methods.

```
    $usr_obj = new WP_User($userID);
    // Remove role
    $usr_obj->remove_role('distributor');
    // Add role
    $usr_obj->add_role('partner');
```

Try this code , it will work definitely.